# Drop Down List one selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down list that is Databound. I have it set up to pick dates to register for classes. I want the selection to show only the first option in order to avoid people registering in the future. I want each class to be as full as possible.

I can either use C#.NET, JQuery, or JScript. Sorry I can't post code.

Comment: Why can't you post code? This feels a bit like you're asking us to write your code for you, not solve a specific problem within your code.

Comment: I know what it feels like, but code is sensitive data. If you do not want to help I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a dropdown if there is going to be only one option?

Some solutions include:

- Bind only the one appropriate item
- Default the selection and disable the dropdown (remember to handle on the server that someone can enable the control on their browser and change the selection)
- Use a label to show what date they are registering for

Comment: I have to have drop down per customer.

Comment: Ok, so since the customer requires you to have a dropdown, ask them how they want to proceed. Do they want only one item in it? Do they want the dropdown disabled?

Comment: I apologize I do not think you understand me. It is not a matter of just binding one piece of data to a drop down list. They basically want all dates for the classes to be loaded in the drop down list, but when the user goes to select the date the most recent class with available seats will show up. Once all vacancies for that session have been met the next available session shows up. Is that a better way of explaining it?

Comment: Ok, as I understand it: You have classes in March, April and May and you want to show only the March classes until they are all booked, then you only want to show April classes. Correct? If so, then you should filter this on the server side. In order to help you out further though, you are going to have to provide some code examples, this is just a practical thing, not me being a jerk.

Comment: I understand and I think nobody is being a jerk. I was looking to bounce logic around maybe, and I think I might have something worked out.